# Calc vs. Overlay for speeding up band math in R 'raster' package?

Tags: raster, r, overlay

Regarding [Speeding up band math in R 'raster' package](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59344), would it be the same to use `overlay` to calculate NDVI instead of `calc` and, if that is not the case, then what is the hidden advantage of `calc` with that particular kind of operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect overlay to be a little slower, but perhaps not much, and the code is perhaps more elegant:

```
f_NDVI2 <- function(x, y) {
  (x-y)/(x+y)
}

NDVI <- overlay(raster[[60]], raster[[75]], fun=f_NDVI2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In manual to 'raster' package it is clearly described in which cases one should use `calc`, `overlay` or simple band math.`calc` is used for operation with a single Raster object and `overlay` is used when calculations involve several Raster objects (or when dataset is too large to be loaded into memory). In my case (you linked to my question) there was only one Raster object of a small size with many bands in it, so there was no point to use `overlay`. And there is one more thing to take into account: can you imagine how would `overlay` function look like to operate over only 2 bands from 100 bands Raster?

Comment: See @RobertH 's solution. That's how it would look like ;-)

Comment: @flowia, nope, he used 2 rasters substructed from initial, not the bands of the given raster.